# Finding Maximum in a Set of Numbers

Tags: number-theory

If I have a set of $n$ numbers: $(a_1,..., a_n)$, then how can I find the two maximum numbers in the set? Suppose that all the numbers are positive integers.

Comment: This is an algorithmic question, not a mathematical question.

Comment: @joriki So there is no mathematical way to solve this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what a mathematical way to solve this, in contrast to an algorithmic way to solve this, would mean. The algorithm is to go through the list, keeping a record of the two largest numbers you've seen so far, in each step comparing the next number with the lesser of the recorded numbers and replacing the latter if it's smaller.

Comment: @joriki What if you shorten it to a finite, say 4.

Answer (score 3):

Completely edited (Misread your question, and you changed your question). The minimum of two numbers is given by:

$\min(a,b) = \large \frac{|a+b|- |a-b|}2$

Of three numbers thus:

$$\min(a,b,c) = \min(\min(a,b),c) = \frac{\left| \frac{|a+b|- |a-b|}2 + c \right| - \left| \frac{|a+b|- |a-b|}2 - c\right| }2 $$

Since you want to find the two maximum numbers out of $3$, just find the minimum and exclude it.

For $n$ numbers, define an algorithm to find the minimum and keep removing each one until two numbers remain (you probably know that).

Comment: I was looking for the maximum two numbers. Can you do that for the case of $n=3$ instead of $n$?

Comment: @theorist: see "for $n=3$" in my answer.

Comment: You only find the $max(a,b,c)$, instead I want two of either $a,b,c$ which are the maximum. So if I had $(1,2,3)$, then I should get $(2,3)$. The point is that I can easily write a program that can do this, but I wanted to see a mathematical way to do this.

Comment: @theorist: check the edit.